# dynamically added rows doesnot have service calls to fetch data from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is being created dynamically and the table rows are being cloned to add more rows by using below code.

```
function addButton(row) {
    var addBtn = document.createElement("button");
    addBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn add-row");
    row.insertCell(-1).appendChild(addBtn);
    addBtn.addEventListener('click', function addRow(event) {
        var rowNode = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
        var newRowNode = rowNode.cloneNode(true);
        rowNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newRowNode, rowNode.nextSibling);
        var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
        delBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn del-row");
        newRowNode.deleteCell();
        newRowNode.insertCell(-1).appendChild(delBtn);
        delBtn.addEventListener('click', function delRow(event) {
            var currentRow = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
            currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);
        });
    });
}
```

but the original row has a service call to fetch the values from DB.
here is the function for fetching data:

```
var lovData = [];
var serviceURL = "/scb/" + title + "/" + propName.replace(/\s/g, '') +
    "lovData";

$.get(serviceURL, function (response) {
    lovData = response;
}).done(function () {
    $("#" + id).autocomplete({
        source: lovData,
        minLength: 0,
        scroll: true
    }).focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
}).fail(function () {

});
```

The issue here is that the row which are being cloned are not making any service call...
how to append the save service call for the cloned node...
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try using $(document).on instead of attaching the event to each row.  This will make sure that any new rows that are created with the same class will have that click event, because the .on() method, when applied to the document, watches the document for changes and then applies your event to whatever matches your selector.

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-row", function(event) {           
    var rowNode = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
    var newRowNode = rowNode.cloneNode(true);
    rowNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newRowNode, rowNode.nextSibling);
    var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    delBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn del-row");
    newRowNode.deleteCell();
    newRowNode.insertCell(-1).appendChild(delBtn);
});

$(document).on("click", ".del-row", function(event) {
    var currentRow = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
    currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);
});
```